# Why str2 is printing "Hi" but not "Hi guys", can somebody explain what's happening in the stack, heap and pool?

Tags: java

Why str2 is printing "Hi" but not "Hi guys"?

Can somebody explain what's happening in the stack, heap and pool?

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    String str1 = "Hi";
    String str2 = str1;
    str1 +=" guys";
    System.out.println(str2);
}
```

Comment: In Java `String`s are immutable. When you use `+=`, you're creating a new `String` and setting `str1` to it. That doesn't change the value of `str2`.

Comment: Strings are immutable. If you "change them", you are creating a new instance (unless it's a pooled instance). Your third line creates such a new instance and assigns it to `str1`. That does NOT change str2, which still references the original `str1`

Comment: thank you very very much

Comment: `int i1 = 5; int i2 = i1; i1 += 2;System.out.println(i2);`  will also print `5` and not `7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is immutable. Thus you are actually creating and assigning a new `String` to the `str1` reference. `StringBuilder` (a mutable type) works as you expected.

```
StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder("Hi");
StringBuilder str2 = str1;
str1.append(" guys");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Outputs

```
Hi guys
```

Comment: thanks, it really helped

Comment: @beckFromDC You're welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow. Don't forget to take the ***free*** [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets string 2 equal to string 1, edits string 1, then prints string 2 so string 2 never gets changed and just prints hi.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str1 = "Hi";
     str1 +=" guys";
     String str2 = str1;
     System.out.println(str2);
}
```

Alternatively you could remove str2 entirely.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String str1 = "Hi";
     str1 +=" guys";
     System.out.println(str1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said already in the comments, instances of `java.lang.String` are immutable. This means that any 'change' to a String is in fact creating a new instance of String that contains the result of that change operation.

Now `str1 += " guys";` may not look that way on the first glance, in particular when you are not familiar with Java at all.

But from the result, that line is the same as

```
str1 = str1.concat( " guys" );
```

(the compiler may even translate both lines to the same byte code). And for `String.concat()` says [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)): "Returns:
*a* string that represents the concatenation of this object's characters followed by the string argument's characters." Not "[…] *the* string with the string argument's characters appended".

This means that after the line `String str2 = str1;` both `str1` and `str2` are the *same* and not only equals, this had changed after the next line …

And now I have to confess that I don't spend any detailed thought about what Java does with the heap, stack and pool when it executes the code from the sample.

I know that Java will create – different from C++ – all object instances only on the heap, *never* on the stack. I know also that Java will maintain a pool for String literals and the values of Strings in general, but I never cared about when a string will end up there or not, and why. And I can imagine that local variables (the place where the references to the objects on heap are kept) will live on the stack as long as they are in scope. And there my knowledge ends …

Comment: I've never seen the compiler use `concat`; it was either `StringBuilder` (<=OpenJdk8) or `StringConcatFactory` (OpenJdk13)... n8

Comment: @user85421: I thought more into the direction that the implementation of `String.concat()` is same as that what the compiler makes from `+=` for Strings … but at least for Java 11/Adopt that implementation of `concat()`is some `byte` array shuffling, neither `StringBuilder` nor `StringConcatFactory` is used at all. But as the results are the same, it *could* use `String.concat()` for implementing `+=`, although the compiler authors may have good reason why they went another way.